# How to select multiple selectors with selectAll?

Tags: select, d3.js, css-selectors, selectall

Is it possible to select multiple selectors in D3 using `selectAll`?

I want something like `svg.selectAll("class1", "circle", "id2")` to select all `circle` elements, `class1` elements and `id2` elements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, you simply put the commas inside the selector string rather than passing separate strings:

```
svg.selectAll(".class1, circle, #id2")
```

I am assuming that "class1" is a css class, "circle" is a tag name, and "id2" is an ID attribute value.

Comment: Do d3's docs explain why a different syntax from CSS selector syntax was chosen?