# Issue with overlapping toolitp d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found [this is a very helpful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757899/how-to-avoid-overlapping-tooltips-of-multi-series-line-chart-d3-js) to create tooltip on line charts. I am following this to work on a line chart now. The difference is the tooltip in my chart has a box/background to contain the value showing in the tooltip, so I add `append('rect')` with `attr('fill', 'white')`.

```
mousePerLine.append('rect').
   attr('width', '38px').
   attr('height', '20px').
   attr('class', 'tooltipRect').
   style('fill', 'white').
   attr('transform', 'translate(5,-13)');
```

To avoid overlapping of text **as well as rect**, I changed line 292 according to a post here [How to select multiple selectors with selectAll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702724/how-to-select-multiple-selectors-with-selectall)

```
  .select("text")

    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate (10,"+(3+ypos[i].off)+")";
    })
```

to

```
  .selectAll(".tooltipRect, text")

    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate (10,"+(3+ypos[i].off)+")";
    })
```

[Here's a fiddle of the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/fk6gfwjr/3/)

However, the tooltips are still overlapping. Can anyone help to figure out what is the cause of the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rects keep overlapping likely because the way you are selecting them.
Why not close the selectiona at the text (keep the text selection above as is) but a make a new selection for the rect:

```
d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
    .select("rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate (5,"+(ypos[i].off - 13)+")";
     });
```

This works for me.
I did the translation based on your initial set up of the rect.  I adjusted the offset on line 286 from 15 to 20 - it looks a bit better.

Comment: Thanks! But the text is overlapping now. My problem is how do I select both rect and text.

Comment: It shouldn't be.  Make sure you have not removed the text selection (lines 292 - 296).  Close that and add the code I posted as a new selection for the rects.  Also, increase the displacement amount you are using on line 286, which is 15, to say 20 or 25 even.