# d3 Classed / Styling with Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While multiple classes can be assigned to one id, but can one assign multiple ids to a class? If yes, then I will save a lot of time / computational resources.

I tried:

```
d3.select('#id1','#id2').classed('my_class',true);
```

I also tried js styling in this manner:

```
d3.select('#id1','#id2').style('display','none');
```

Only the first id works.

Is there a succinct way to handle such a case? I would be surprised if there wasn't a work-around in some shape or form. I just can't find one in this situation.

Comment: If d3 uses css/jquery like selection it's probably just `d3.select('#id1, #id2')` edit they do [D3 Selecting Elements](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selecting-elements)

Comment: Interesting thought. I tried it just now, no dice. Must be slightly different than jquery

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to apply some styling to multiple elements whose ids are in the form `id1, id2, id3...`?

Comment: @ArashHowaida If that's not a solution then I'm afraid I can't be of much more help

Comment: @sparta93 Actually I just used that since it was easy notation. My real id names are not of any type of pattern. Just names.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702724/how-to-select-multiple-selectors-with-selectall

Comment: @mrsq Hmm, yea, that's interesting. So I guess I need to use `selectAll` instead of `select`. It works this way. I'm not sure if there is a big trade-off in efficiency or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments below the question have all the information to fix the problem. However, for future readers, I'd like to write some points here.

First of all: always read the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md). With few exceptions, it has all information you need. For instance, let's see what it says about [select](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#select):

> Selects the **first** element that matches the specified selector **string**. (emphases mine)

Now let's see your code:

```
d3.select('#id1','#id2')
//              ^--------- two strings, separated by a comma
```

That's not a string. This is a string:

```
d3.select('#id1, #id2')
//              ^--------- just one string here!
```

Second problem: `select` selects the **first** element that matches the string. So, you want `selectAll`, not `select`.

**Solution**: it has to be:

```
d3.selectAll("#id1, #id")
```

Here is a demo, click the button:

```js
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  d3.selectAll("#c2, #c5").attr("fill", "brown");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<svg>
  <circle id="c1" cx="20" cy="30" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle id="c2" cx="60" cy="30" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle id="c3" cx="100" cy="30" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle id="c4" cx="140" cy="30" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle id="c5" cx="180" cy="30" r="10" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Since OP is particularly concerned about performance issues, it is worth noting, that this approach is by far outperformed by the solution brought forward by Nobita's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42986738/4235784). Although, admittedly, this looks much cleaner and more intuitive and—as usual—comes with a nice explanation.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for the appreciation but - surprisingly? - I would argue that Gerardo's approach is probably more performant. Instead of selecting multiple times it's always better to select once, and that's what selectAll does as it uses querySelectorAll under the hood (see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/selectAll.js) and [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selectorAll.js#L7) in the source). Also, it's more idiomatic for D3, Hence I upvoted his answer.

Comment: @Nobita Although this might intuitively seem logical, your approach is in fact *way* faster than Gerardo's. Executing my [performance test](https://jsperf.com/d3-multi-select-by-id) on Chrome the test case #2, which implements your answer, is more than ten times faster then this answer's approach. Substituting the inner selection with the native `document.getElementById()` will further double that speed. The results vary across browers, with the browser*esque* IE 11 being the slowest, but are all faster than using a complex selector string.

Comment: @altocumulus I am a bit surprised but won't argue with that! Can't beat perf tests :D

Comment: Wow very interesting, thanks for explaining the efficiency dimension so well. On a side note, I don't mean to upsell or anything, but your circle example reminded me that I have an unanswered d3 post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958915/d3-geo-circle-in-miles), if there is political will to look it over :)

Comment: @ArashHowaida if a question has not received attention, you can always set a bounty. Normally, the question itself is so upvoted (I just did it) that you end up receiving your bounty back.

Answer (score 4):

You can store your IDs in an array and map over it

```
var ids = ['#g1', '#g2']

ids.map(el => d3.select(el).classed('red', true))
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/49ktsw63/1/) or here below:

```js
var ids = ['#g1', '#g2']

ids.map(el => d3.select(el).classed('red', true));
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background: teal;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="g1"></div>
<div id="g2"></div>
<div id="g3"></div>
<div id="g4"></div>
```